# addData() dropped from latest chart.js 2.1.3 - whats up?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I've been reading the docs, and there are ways to replace the data then update the chart:

```
myLineChart.data.datasets[0].data[2] = 50; // Would update the first dataset's value of 'March' to be 50
myLineChart.update(); // Calling update now animates the position of March from 90 to 50.
```

https://github.com/chartjs/Chart.js/blob/master/docs/07-Advanced.md

But `addData()` appears to be gone, am I stuck with making my own addData for local data and then updating the whole chart? or am I missing something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `update()` handles adding data too. Just push your new data / labels into the config object that you passed when creating the chart and then call `update()`

For instance,

```
var config = {
  type: 'line',
  data: {
    labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
    datasets: [{
      label: "My First dataset",
      data: [65, 0, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40],
      fill: false
    }]
  }
};

var ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, config);

setTimeout(function(){
    config.data.labels.push('Test');
    config.data.datasets[0].data.push(3);
    myChart.update();
}, 1000);
```

---

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/zpnx8ppb/

Comment: Also possible to update current dataset with "new" data:

`setTimeout(function(){
    config.data.labels.push('February');
    // config.data.datasets[0].data.push(3);
    config.data.labels = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"];
    config.data.datasets[0].data = [25, 10, 80, 81, 56, 85, 40];
    myChart.update();
}, 2000);
`